# How to query NodeJS stream 'meta data'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, haskell, stream, meta

I have a program with several long pipes with several transforms.

e.g.

```
socket.pipe(ta).pipe(tb).pipe(tc);
...
tc.pipe(other_socket);
```

What is the best way of adding/reading meta data to/from the pipe?

For example: `ta` accumulates and breaks packets into lines.  `tb` needs to prefix each line with data based on the originating IP address (if any).

How can `tb` get the `remoteAddress` from its input?

There seem to be some similarities with prototypical inheritance here.  i.e. `tb` should ask `ta` (which lacks the property) then `ta` should ask `socket` (which has the property).

I'm looking for a general approach to adding and reading metadata from pipes, as I have other more complex, but analogous issues.

I'm currently solving this issue by using 'Object Streams' consisting of objects with `meta` and `payload` properties.  Each transform has to do its stuff to `payload` and most leave `meta` alone.  This solution is ugly, especially as I've had to create a new `xnet` module which looks like `net` but produces these augmented objects, rather than plain buffers or strings.

(Haskellers might recognise this solution as a Monad, where I'm lifting most of the stream transforms I use into a "meta" Monad.  I'm still learning Haskell, so this observation may be incorrect.)

Comment: If the meta data is read-only data for particular instance of pipeline execution then why not pass this data while creating the individual pipes. Something like : `socket.pipe(new Ta(address))`

Comment: In terms of Haskell, it sounds like a Reader moand, where the Pipeline execution function takes a Reader which full fill all the meta data requirements of individual pipes of the pipeline

Comment: @Ankur that's an interesting solution, but it's made me realise that the meta data does need to be per 'packet'.  When multiple TCP connections merge their data into one pipeline, a downstream consumer will only be able to find out about the meta data if it is in the packet.  (Different packets will come from different TCP connections.)

Comment: There's a massive amount of work around these concepts in the Haskell community called [`pipes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), [`conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), and [`io-streams`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams). The basic idea is [due to Oleg](http://okmij.org/ftp/Streams.html), though is quite complex. Mario Blazevic did a great job presenting a simplified, streamlined version in [Issue 19 of the Monad Reader](http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/issue19.pdf).

Comment: @Ankur, I've gone with your solution.  If you paste it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the meta data is read-only data for particular instance of pipeline execution then why not pass this data while creating the individual pipes. Something like : socket.pipe(new Ta(address))

In terms of Haskell, it sounds like a Reader moand, where the Pipeline execution function takes a Reader which full fill all the meta data requirements of individual pipes of the pipeline

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pipe` event:

```
tb.on('pipe', function(ta) {
  console.log('getting data from', ta.remoteAddress);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but `ta` doesn't have a `remoteAddress` only the `socket` at the start does.

Comment: Then, can you propagate the initial stream by listening to the sucessive pipe events?